# href click event vs. btn click event. Confused?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm building a message center.  From their inbox, my users can select multiple checkboxes, click the "Delete" button, and selected messages are removed.  Works great:

html:

```
<input type="submit" id="DeleteButton" value="Delete" />
```

script:

```
 $('#DeleteButton').click (function() {
 var selected = new Array();
 $("input:checkbox[name=message]:checked").each(function() {
 selected.push($(this).val());
 });
 var selectedString = selected.join(",");
        <cfoutput>$.post("SecComm.cfc?method=deleteMessages&recipientID=#session.ID#", {selected: selected },</cfoutput>
        function(html) {
                        loadMessages();
        });  
    });
```

The problem I'm having is where I allow users to move messages to any folders they may have set up.  I'm using similar script but cannot get it working with the href:

```
<div class="moveMessages"> 
        <a href="" class="move"  id="7">My new folder</a>
</div>
```

script:

```
$('.move').click(function(){ 
 var folderID = $(this).attr('id');                                
 var selected = new Array();
 $("input:checkbox[name=message]:checked").each(function() {
  selected.push($(this).val());
 });
        $.post(
            "SecComm.cfc?method=moveMessage&recipientID=#session.ID#", 
            {messageID: selected },
            {folderID: folderID },
            function() {
                loadMessages();
            });         
    });
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.  Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The href has default functionality that may be conflicting with what you're doing. Make sure you're passing the event object in and then use preventDefault to stop the browser from performing the default functionality of the href.

```
$('.move').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Things that seem to be wrong:

1. Prevent the default behavior for the event.
2. Pass in the data as one object and not as two separate arguments.

```
$('.move').click(function( event ){ 
    var folderID = $(this).attr('id');                                
    var selected = new Array();
    $("input:checkbox[name=message]:checked").each(function() {
        selected.push($(this).val());
     });
     $.post(
            "SecComm.cfc?method=moveMessage&recipientID=#session.ID#", 
                { messageID: selected, folderID: folderID }, 
                function() {
                    loadMessages();
               });         
      event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Id's cannot be just a number.

Use for example `id="message-7"`

Also see: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Or in your case it would be better to do:

```
<a href="" class="move"  data-id="7">My new folder</a>
```

and access it using:

```
$('.move').click(function(e){ 
  var folderID = $(this).data('id');
```

Also:

add `e.preventdefault();`

to prevent the hyperlink from navigating away from the page.

Answer (score 0):

`$.post` method's second argument is data or success handler. You are passing 2 different arguments for data, one for `messageID` and another for `folderID`. You should pass a single object with all the data elements in it. Try this

```
     $.post(
        "SecComm.cfc?method=moveMessage&recipientID=#session.ID#", 
        {messageID: selected, folderID: folderID },
        function() {
            loadMessages();
     });
```

Since you have not set anything in the `href` attribute of anchor it will not appera as a link in FF. Set `javascript:void(0)` or `#` at least. If you set `#`, after clicking on anchor you will the browser will scroll to the top. In order to avoid that you should prevent the default behavior of anchor by calling `e.preventDefault()` inside anchor `click` event handler where `e` is the event object in the handler.

```
$('.move').click(function(e){ 
   e.preventDefault();
   ...
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is... its not very well described, however from experience and from your mention of the `href` of the link I would say that your link is propagating... which is "refreshing" the page as it were.

So my answer (unless I get some more information) is to add

`return false;`

at the end of the `click(function(){ });` eg:

```
$('.move').click(function(){ 
 var folderID = $(this).attr('id');                                
 var selected = new Array();
 $("input:checkbox[name=message]:checked").each(function() {
  selected.push($(this).val());
 });
        $.post(
            "SecComm.cfc?method=moveMessage&recipientID=#session.ID#", 
            {messageID: selected },
            {folderID: folderID },
            function() {
                loadMessages();
            });         
    return false;
});
```

And that will stop the link from propagating.

Comment: please note the Rusty's answer doesn't do the same thing. What you are doing is basically: `e.preventDefault()` AND `e.stopPropagation();`. That brings up the following 'flaw' in your answer. 'And that will stop the link from propagating.' Although you are right it's not the propagtion you want to stop here but the default action.

Comment: Thank you all.  All info was helpful.  The "return false" was my first try and resulted in me actually seeing the error.

Comment: oh right peehaa, never knew that. Whats the difference between preventDefault() and stopPropagation()? I was under the impression they were similar/the same?